# Mean of a function of a Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $X(t)$ a Poisson Process with parameter $\lambda$, Consider the compound poisson process:

$$A(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{X(t)}Y_i$$

If $\{Y_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ are a i.i.d. random variables $exp(\theta$.Define:
$$T=\inf\{t\ge 0: A(t)>a\}$$
for $a>0$.

Find $E[T]$.

${\bf idea}$
I Think that a way to compute this mean is find the moment generating function of T, but I couldn't find it. There is a simplest way of compute it?

Comment: You might try a simplified version of the problem where the number of summands is not random, but is large enough that after summing $m$ of them, the sum is above $a$ - what is the expected number of summands?

Comment: This reasoning extends to your initial problem with conditional probability: What's the probability that the sum exceeds $a$ at time $t$, given that there have been $k$ jumps by time $t$? (Observe that if we condition on the number of jumps, the number of summands is deterministic.)

Comment: Note that the first time $A$ exceeds $a$ has to be at the time of a jump.

Comment: Lastly, what is the probability that the $k$th jump occurs at time $t$?

Comment: @manofbear Frankly, even knowing how to solve the question, I fail to see how your four (!) comments can help the OP to do so. Care to explain?

Comment: To explain the formula below and/or get a more intrinsic understanding of the problem, note that in full generality, $$E(T)=\int_0^\infty P(T>t)dt$$ with $$P(T>t)=P(A_t<a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(A_t<a\mid X_t=k)P(X_t=k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(S_k<a)P(X_t=k)$$ where $S_0=0$ and $S_k=Y_1+\cdots+Y_k$. Thus, $$E(T)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(S_k<a)J_k$$ where $$J_k=\int_0^\infty P(X_t=k)dt$$ Note that $J_k$ is the time the process $(X_t)$ spends in the state $k$ hence, for every $k$, $J_k=1/\lambda$, and $E(T)=n(a)/\lambda$ where $$n(a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(S_k<a)$$

Comment: ... Now, $(S_k)$ is the collection of time events in a homogenous Poisson process $(N_t)$ with intensity $1/\theta$ hence $$n(a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(N_a\geqslant k)=1+E(N_a)=1+\theta a$$ which yields $$E(T)=\frac1{\lambda}(1+\theta a)$$

Answer (score 2):

$
\begin{align*}
P(T\leq t)&=P(A(t)>a) \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A(t)>a\mid X(t)=n)P(X(t)=n) \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\big(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i>a\big)\frac{(\lambda t)^n e^{-\lambda t}}{n!} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n,\theta a)}{(n-1)!}\frac{(\lambda t)^ne^{-\lambda t}}{n!}.
\end{align*}
$

The last line is due to the sum of $n$ i.i.d. $\text{Exp}(\theta)$ random variables having the distribution of a $\text{Gamma}(n,\theta)$ random variable.

Differentiate with respect to $t$ to get the pdf as

$
\begin{align*}
p(t)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n,\theta a)}{(n-1)!}\left(\frac{\lambda^n t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}-\frac{\lambda^{n+1}t^n}{n!}\right)e^{-\lambda t} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+1,\theta a)}{n!}-\frac{\Gamma(n,\theta a)}{(n-1)!}\right)\frac{\lambda^{n+1}t^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}+\Gamma(1,\theta a)\lambda e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align*}
$

The expectation is

$
\begin{align*}
E(T)&=\int_0^{\infty}tp(t)\,dt \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+1,\theta a)}{n!}-\frac{\Gamma(n,\theta a)}{(n-1)!}\right)\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{\infty}(\lambda t)^{n+1}e^{-\lambda t}\,dt+\Gamma(1,\theta a)\int_0^{\infty}\lambda te^{-\lambda t}\,dt \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+1,\theta a)}{n!}-\frac{\Gamma(n,\theta a)}{(n-1)!}\right)\frac{(n+1)!}{n!\lambda}+\frac{\Gamma(1,\theta a)}{\lambda} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\Gamma(n+1,\theta a)-n\Gamma(n,\theta a)\right)\frac{n+1}{n!\lambda}+\frac{\Gamma(1,\theta a)}{\lambda} \\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\Gamma(n+1,\theta a)-n\Gamma(n,\theta a))\frac{n+1}{n!} \\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\theta a)^ne^{-\theta a}}{n!}(n+1) \\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}(\theta a+1).
\end{align*}
$